# Generating pairs of elliptic $\mathbb{F}_q$-curves isogenous over $\mathbb{F}_q$ such that nobody knows an $\mathbb{F}_q$-isogeny between them

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, elliptic-curve-generation, isogeny

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a large finite field. What if I invent how to efficiently construct pairs of elliptic "cryptographically strong" $\mathbb{F}_q$-curves $E_1$, $E_2$ isogenous over $\mathbb{F}_q$, that is $\#E_1(\mathbb{F}_q) = \#E_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$, in such a way that nobody (including me) knows an $\mathbb{F}_q$-isogeny between them ? Is this useful in discrete logarithm or isogeny-based cryptography ?

Comment: Yes, it's interesting. Please do it.